# html/jquery shows different image than expected

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new in programming. When i am  trying  to run code below i expect image with id = "3" to show up. Instead of that, image with id = "5" is showing up. I think it's fundamental but can't figure out what is going wrong. Any suggestion?

```
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-cookie-master/src/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .frame {
    height: 368px;
    width: 245px;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 16px;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-top-color: #FFF;
    border-right-color: #C0C;
    border-bottom-color: #C0C;
    border-left-color: #C0C;
}
</style>

<script>
function slider(){  
    $('#3').show();
    };    
</script>


</head>

<body  onload="slider()">


<div class="frame">
    <img id="1" src="images/slideshow/device1.png" alt="" style="position:absolute"/>
    <img id="2 "src="images/slideshow/device2.png" alt="" style="position:absolute"/>
     <img id="3" src="images/slideshow/device3.png" alt="" style="position:absolute"/>
    <img id="4" src="images/slideshow/device4.png" alt="" style="position:absolute"/>
    <img id="5" src="images/slideshow/device5.png" alt="" style="position:absolute"/>


</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be $('.frame #3').show();   with the space between class and id selector?

Comment: id's should be unique, so you can just use `$('#3').show()`

Comment: I know this must be the solution since everybody suggest it but ..nope. I updated my full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you aren't hiding the other elements. They are all shown, but absolutely positioned on top of one another. Just add `display:none` to your images using the following CSS:

```
.frame img {
  display: none;
}
```

**Note:** jQuery 3.0 alpha1 has [changed the behavior](http://blog.jquery.com/2015/07/13/jquery-3-0-and-jquery-compat-3-0-alpha-versions-released/) of `.show()` and this method won't work with jQuery versions that follow the new logic.

You can see this in action in the snippet below.

```js
$('#3').show();
```

```css
.frame {
    height: 368px;
    width: 245px;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 16px;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-top-color: #FFF;
    border-right-color: #C0C;
    border-bottom-color: #C0C;
    border-left-color: #C0C;
}

.frame img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frame">
    <img id="1" src="images/slideshow/device1.png" alt="" style="position:absolute"/>
    <img id="2 "src="images/slideshow/device2.png" alt="" style="position:absolute"/>
     <img id="3" src="images/slideshow/device3.png" alt="" style="position:absolute"/>
    <img id="4" src="images/slideshow/device4.png" alt="" style="position:absolute"/>
    <img id="5" src="images/slideshow/device5.png" alt="" style="position:absolute"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just miss space in jquery selector, your selector means element with class frame && id 3. You have to write it like this.

$('.frame #3').show();
or
$('.frame').find('#3').show();

Answer (score 0):

I think you should seperate the selectors:

```
$('.frame #3').show();
```

**EDIT**

Or just use the ID as they have to be unique

```
$('#3').show();
```

Comment: I make the change but problem insists

Comment: you can just use the id. I think this will work aswell as they have to be unique.. check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can show 3rd image using this, because u have used image position absolute so all image show on page but other image hide behind image 5th so .
you need to add jquery cdn library...

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js" ></script>
```

using this you can see 3rd image...

```
<script>
function slider(){  
    $("#1,#2,#4,#5").hide();
    $('#3').show();   
    };    
</script>
```